# Does vector calculus, graph theory or statistics make much use of sequences and series?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Just wondering whether learning about sequences and series while I have the chance would be helpful for my future math endeavors (which consist of statistics, vector calculus and graph theory. Those aren't courses I'm taking in particular, but instead are just fields whose techniques I expect to have to use at some point).

Sorry if this comes off as me being lazy: sequences and series are actually my favorite part of math because they can always provide exact answers to things; they never need to approximate (I'm referring mostly to infinite series here). It's just that there is much I need to learn, and I'm wanting to prioritize the things I'll need to know in the near future.

Comment: You need to understand series to do integrals.  Integrals are very important in vector calculus (I taught that for several years) and statistics.  Sequences include limits which are important for statistics (Random Processes, Law of Large Numbers, ...).  I am no expert on graph theory, but I am thinking that you don't use sequences and series much in graph theory. However, leaning almost any kind of mathematics helps you with all other mathematics just because it teaches your brain how to think very precisely.  I would say precision reasoning is more important in mathematics than other fields.

Comment: If you wish to learn mathematics, then you **will** need to know sequences and series.

Comment: To my knowledge sequence and series like topics pop up  somewhat frequently in probability theory. For example, the Gamma distribution and the Beta distribution both utilize the respective Beta and Gamma functions (different from, actually sub-components of their respective PDFs). These functions act to scale the PDFs such that they integrate to 1. Likewise, in the binomial PMF, factorials play a big role, which is also related to sequences and series.

Answer (score 2):

While sequences and series may not be directly related to the areas of study you mentioned, being comfortable working with these objects is essential to being a well-rounded mathematician.

For starters, working with sequences and series is often exposure people have with dealing with infinity. Being comfortable with infinite series will be essential for doing any higher math. But, in particular, you mentioned statistics. And for statistics, you'll need to know probability theory, which will require that you understand some measure theory and functional analysis, which will require that you understand sequences and series! So this is definitely a topic to pay attention to.

I would say that all of these introductory topics are ones you should pay close attention to. You're building a foundation for your mathematical knowledge, so skimming a topic or skipping it altogether will not serve you well. It's much harder to go back and learn something you missed than it is to learn it well in the first place.